# Object emit light distance

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light

I created an object, and I wanted it to glow. I used to just place points of light around it, and parent them to it, but using the emit option in the materials seemed so much easier. 
But when I gave it an a higher emit than 0, it went only a small distance before the light stopped. I turned it up to 200, and the object was white with light, but the light didn't go any farther.
Oh and I changed the color, and nothing happened.

Comment: I'm going to recommend that you use Cycles instead of Blender Internal. When you start using Indirect lighting, you're essentially trying features that where added on because they where new. Blender Internal was never built for Indirect lighting and correct reflections. Cycles was build with these in mind, so it achieves better results at about the same speed, or faster. Especially if you get a good GPU or have a good CPU.

Comment: OK... I was afraid of that.
I got a couple rigs for my first animation (I'm starting with Minecraft animations, because I really like Minecraft and it seemed a good way to start) And they all used Blender Internal. So I'll have to retexture/remodel everything for this. I knew I was going to have to do that eventually, I just wanted some more practice with it overall before I made it, so I had an idea on what I need. I'm glad this place is here and active so I'm not going it completely alone.

Comment: You'll just have to learn about the materials. The textures will go across pretty easily. Yeah, we're here and ready to help you out when you need it.

Comment: Thank you!
Really quick, before I have to go for tonight, (I don't think this warrents a whole post), how do I chat? I have twenty rep, but it says I "need twenty reputation before I can chat" and I don't see a place to type.

Comment: It might take a bit for the rep to sync up. If you can't get it to work today, try tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

To get this kind of interaction in **Blender render** you'll have to enable **Indirect lighting** with the **Approximate** Gather method.

From the [Blender Reference Manual's page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/world/indirect_lighting.html):

> Indirect Lighting only works with Approximate gather method.

[image]

The emission color of the emitting object's surface comes from the diffuse color multiplied by the emission strenght (Emit).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using indirect lighting with BI does increase render times a decent amount though, right?

Comment: Yes, it does. The engine has more things to calculate.

Comment: Oh. Wait.
So I've had the indirect lighting activated for a while... But the question for me is "How do I increase the distance of the light" Right now it only goes a short distance, no matter how much I increase the emit. I want it to illuminate a large area.

Comment: @BookWyrm17 My answer was completely irrelevant then. Sorry I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Increase the strenght as you were doing. It should work.

Comment: @Carlo yeah, I just get a bit nervous once you start using Indirect lighting in BI. It seems much more experimental to me since those features weren't built into the design of the engine originally.

Comment: There is somewhere an answer that solve that @TARDISMaker, I'm trying to find it and add a link. Anyway I would discourage to tweak the color of the object only, it would probably looks fake (the light on the bottom could result lighter than the object itself).

Comment: No no, the reason I made the post is because I can't figure out why the distance doesn't increase with the power.
No Tardis, I only remembered the color after the fact, and reasoned I would mention it while I was on the topic. Sorry if I was unclear.
@Carlo what strength do I increase?

Comment: The "emission strenght", aka "the amount of light to emit" is the slider called "Emit" in the Shading Panel of the Material's tab

Comment: Ok @Carlo
Sorry I wasn't able to reply earlier. I tried to increase the Emit in the Materials tab, but all it did was make it brighter, and the light did not travel any farther. I want it to light up a large area, but I can't find a setting to make it do that. I've been told to use Cycles, and that seems like the smart thing to do, I would just like to know if it is possible now to increase the distance in Blender Render.

Comment: I've added a gif showing how the Emit property influence the strenght of the emission end consequentially the influenced area on the plane. You can surely achieve a similar result with cycles too.