# best way to add a glowing material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to make a model of the GN blades from gundam, tried different materials, like emission, but it doesnt look good altogether, tried turning the blade translucent green, and inserting a rectangle with a white emmision but still doesnt look good. any tips?

I'm using a black low light background and another with a diffuse with room
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Welcome! Could you show what you achieved so far and explain why your are not satisfied with the effect (e.g "the edges are not sharp, the reflection is absent...")? Here's a possibly related question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39803/object-emit-light-distance/39806#39806

Comment: You can substitute one images or merge two in one with an image editor to make room for another or use links.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/post-processing-lightsabers-in-blender ?